# Microsoft Assessment and Planning Toolkit for Windows server 2003

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone please tell me where I can find Microsoft Assessment and Planning Toolkit for Windows server 2003?
I tried using version 8.0 but it fails to install on Windows server 2003.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Version 7.0 available [here](http://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Assessment-and-Planning-Toolkit/3000-2064_4-75451526.html) that supports Operating system:
Windows XP/2003/Vista/Server 2008/7.

Look like Microsoft does not have it on their site. the latest is 8.0 which supports only Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8 Pro, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Vista Business, Windows Vista Enterprise, Windows Vista Ultimate.

**NO Windows 2003 support.**

some good links can be found at [MAP Toolkit Useful References](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mapblog/archive/2012/07/13/map-toolkit-useful-references.aspx)